# Find and replace in Visual Studio code in a selection

Tags: replace, visual-studio-code

I have the following line in a file I'm editing in VSCode:

`...............111.........111.............111..`

I want to replace all `.`s with `0`s. However, when I highlight the line and do a find/replace for `.`s, *all* the `.`s in the document are replaced, not just the ones in the line I've select, even when I toggle the "Find in selection" button. Is this a bug? In other editors, if I select a chunk of text and then do a find/replace, it will only find/replace matches within the selected block.

Below is a snippet that you should be able to reproduce the issue with. The `...............111.........111.............111..` line is inside the `test_unicode` function.

```
def test_simple2(self):
        """Simple CSV transduction test with empty fields, more complex idx, different pack_size.

        100011000001000 ->
        ..........111....................111..........11111..........111..
        """
        field_width_stream = pablo.BitStream(int('1000110001000001000', 2))
        idx_marker_stream = pablo.BitStream(int('11101', 2))
        pack_size = 4
        target_format = TransductionTarget.JSON
        csv_column_names = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"]

        pdep_marker_stream = pablo.BitStream(generate_pdep_stream(field_width_stream,
                                                                  idx_marker_stream,
                                                                  pack_size, target_format,
                                                                  csv_column_names))
        self.assertEqual(pdep_marker_stream.value, 63050402300395548)

    def test_unicode(self):
        """Non-ascii column names.

        Using UTF8. Hard coded SON boilerplate byte size should remain the same, column name
        boilerplate bytes should expand.

        100010010000000 ->
        2 + 4 + 9     2 + 4 + 6     2 + 4 + 7
        ...............111.........111.............111..
        """
        field_width_stream = pablo.BitStream(int('100010001000', 2))
        idx_marker_stream = pablo.BitStream(1)
        pack_size = 64
        target_format = TransductionTarget.JSON
        csv_column_names = ["한국어", "中文", "English"]

        pdep_marker_stream = pablo.BitStream(generate_pdep_stream(field_width_stream,
                                                                  idx_marker_stream,
                                                                  pack_size, target_format,
                                                                  csv_column_names))
        self.assertEqual(pdep_marker_stream.value, 1879277596)
```

I'm using VSCode 1.12.2 in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: looked through all answers . this is an awful failing of `vscode`

Comment: `ALT+L` with selection, on regular **replacement all**

Answer (score 202, accepted):

I was able to get it to work but the workflow is poor:

1. <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open Find/Replace
2. Select your line of text
3. Click the "Find in selection" icon to the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>⎇</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> on macOS)
4. Enter your find and replace characters in their inputs
5. Click the Replace all icon

It works but you have to go through the workflow all over again for each new selection (except for <kbd>CTR</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> of course).  BTW I have the exact same behavior in Sublime Text.

Could you go with a regExp to find your lines?  Do they contain only .'s and 1's?

Comment: I could do it with regex in this case, but it seems like overkill. And in the general case, I think a more straight forward find/replace tool would be useful . I might open an issue on their git hub page.

Comment: Opening the issue is a good idea.  I'm surprised that both VSCode and Sublime make you jump through these hoops for such a straightforward task.  For example, you can not invert items 3 and 4 above in my answer - that seems prone to error and frustration.

Comment: Issue has been opened: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/27083. Will post an answer if they come out with a fix.

Comment: the suggestion in that thread which works for me on the latest update is changing this setting (File > Preferences > Settings and then paste it in):
"editor.find.autoFindInSelection": true

Comment: Performing Replace In Selection with VSCode's default behavior is not quite convenient for me too. Therefore, I've just written a VSCode extension for that. Although later I found this post and think the settings `"editor.find.autoFindInSelection": "multiline"` may seem improve the situation somehow, my extension has several advantages beyond VSCode's Replace, and is especially good at replacing short search patterns (in regex). My extension is "Quick Replace In Selection", here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnnywong.quick-replace-in-selection

Comment: Why is this the only editor I've ever used where find/replace in selection is rocket science? I don't understand how the VS Code team managed to buck decades of precedent in favor of such counterintuitive behavior. Baffling.

Comment: The process sucks big time. Having to click here and there just to make something so FOUNDAMENTAL to code editing work correctly while MS's Visual Studio have got it right for DECADES is a joke. This needs to be fixed ASAP. Ctrl+H with text being selected should apply to that text ONLY. Period.

Answer (score 71):

*This is a more general answer for other users who come here just wanting to use basic find and replace functionality.*

On Mac you can press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open Find and Replace:

[image]

Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open Find and then click the little triangle on the left to show the Replace field:

[image]

Press the four-line icon on the right to search within a selection:

[image]

Comment: I have sublime keymap enabled so not sure if it works for all, but i was able to use CMD + OPT + f to open up find and replace immediately

Comment: @Julian, nice one! I don't have sublime keymap enabled and it still works. I updated the answer. Thank you.

Comment: thanks! also, forgot to mention a couple other fun facts: If you CMD + ENTER that will set your find and replace for the entire file. Otherwise, you can step through each one with enter. You can also do a project-global find and replace by doing CMD + SHIFT + H

Comment: Command + Option + F enabled it for the first use, afterwards Command + F will be enough to get the find/replace bar.

Comment: If you do it by ENTER, how do you skip ?

Comment: btw, the icon on the right with the 4 lines is the `Toggle Find in Selection`

Comment: Yes, that icon on the right with a few horizontal lines is the key to do find&replacement in selection!!!

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question? The question was about finding and replacing within a particular section of the file, as opposed to the whole file.

Comment: @Junglemath, You're right. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 42):

From the VSCode devs:

> We used to enable find in selection automatically when opening the
> find widget with a selection, but it was too easy to trigger
> accidentally and produced a lot of complaints. You probably want to
> set "editor.find.autoFindInSelection": true which will make it work
> the way you expect.

The [VSCode GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/27083#issuecomment-306258946) has more details if anyone is interested.

EDIT: The `autoFindInSelection` option is available starting from VSCode 1.13. That version is currently in development (as of 6/7/2017), so this fix won't work until the new version is released.

Comment: This will not solve the problem though... The only issue is that if you do consecutive F/R each time you select a new set of text **you need to refocus the find field** in order for it to change its *find context*.

Comment: Changing the setting seemed to do the trick for me, although VS Code still marks _all appearances of the search term_ in the whole document, even if it will only replace the ones in the selection.

Comment: The setting `editor.find.autoFindInSelection` now expects a string, not a boolean. Valid values are: "never", "always", "multiline"

Comment: Also, auto find in selection does not work for me when editing a Python Jupyter Notebook `.ipynb` (although it works well when editing `.py` files).

Comment: thank f*ck for this. Why on earth is this off by default. pure madness

Answer (score 27):

I found the following workflow to be fairly painless:

1. Select text region with mouse or keyboard.
2. Ctrl+H to toggle find and replace
3. Alt+L to toggle find in selection
4. Ctrl+Alt+Enter to replace all  (or enter to replace individually)

Comment: How is this different than the answer above?  You just omitted actually inputting the find and replace text and swapped the order of the first two steps which doesn't matter.

Comment: Alt+L commentary over mouse click makes it different (read: better)

Comment: Yes! This is the natural flow - **first** select text, then open `Find & Replace`, then select `Find in selection`, then type term to find and replacement term and finally `Replace all`.

Answer (score 20):

Since sometimes we might have similarly named things so you don't want to select everything, one of my favorites shortcut sequences is to [select the next occurrence](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multiple-selections-multicursor):

1. Use <kbd>shift</kbd> and arrows to highlight the term you want to match.
2. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> to highlight the next occurrence of the term.

[image: next occurrence selection]

The [Basic Editing in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics) documentation page has some extremely useful variations on find and replace. One extremely useful shortcut is the [Column (Box) Selection](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_column-box-selection).

Comment: If you press CTRL + d once to often: how do you undo the last selection?

Comment: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `d`

Comment: that opened my debug window on factory settings.
I found the command -> CTRL + U

Comment: You can edit your shortcuts in VS Code if you want. I don't know why yours was mapped to that, mine was working with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `d` since the beginning as far as I remember, and it seems to be a much more natural shortcut.

Answer (score 11):

## For mac

1. Press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> to bring up this menu:

[image]

2. Press the little icon that has the arrow pointing at it above (3 horizontal bars)
3. Select the text you want to do a find and replace in, and enter the 'find' and 'replace' fields
4. Press this icon:

[image]

5. That's all!

Comment: thx.  i detest needing to use mouse just to do find and replace.  This is nigh on a showstopper for vscode

Answer (score 8):

Okay, this is really dumb, at first I felt really stupid when I finally found this, then I realized its just VS Code which has a bad interface.

The key is, there are TWO TOOLS here,
Search/Replace (the pane on the left at the top of the Explorer) and Find/Replace (which is a dialogue which opens when you press CTRL-F)

THESE ARE NOT THE SAME TOOL!!

- SEARCH-REPLACE is a tool written for project-wide searches and
  changes
- FIND-REPLACE is a small dialogue best suited for more
  surgical editing.

i.e. you should use FIND-REPLACE!

[find replace window image with find-in-selection highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFEQ7.png)

Also, its SUPER IMPORTANT to follow these steps in the right order, or it doesn't give the expected results.

1. Press CTRL-F to open the find dialogue (usually opens in the top right)
2. press the little arrow to the right of the find field which opens the replace input field
3. ensure "find in selection" is turned off (i.e. not highlighted)
4. type in the fields the strings you want to search/replace
5. select the text you want to do a search/replace within.
6. Now press "find in selection" (or type ALT-L)
7. You should see only highlighting in the area you previously selected.
8. Now you can click either "replace all" (CTRL-ALT-ENTER) or line-by-line "replace" (ENTER)

I hope this helps.

My suggestion to VSC developers, there should be a refresh button so that after you have selected the area of interest, and you already have your find and replace strings defined, you can select a new region and click "refresh find" instead of needing to repeat steps 3 to 8.

Comment: You can press CTRL+H to get the FIND-REPLACE dialog with replacement field already expanded. But yeah, this little feature violates several guidelines of UI design at once, and should be improved. Bookmarking this because I will surely need it again.

Comment: I'm not going to be pressing anything for find /replace. Gotta be keyboard driven. If this is the closest we get bye bye vscode

Comment: This is the only full answer to the question. Technically, step 4 can also be made after step 6. I need to deselect "Find in Selection" or close the search prompt when I want to find matches in another selection. Closing is better because it preserves any new selection. I don't know any other editor with such a bad find/replace functionality. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Outstanding! Not stupid. I've been using `sed -i '...'` for global project replacement because I had no clue what the global search/replace was for project wide application. `Ctrl + shift + f` will bring it up. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Just ran into this, my solution was to do

1. command + N to create a new file
2. paste my selection in there
3. do my find and replace operations on that while file
4. copy result back on top of my original selection

Answer (score 6):

On Mac:

- Select the text
- Press command + shift + L

Answer (score 3):

For those where it still does not work, there is one step omitted in all of the above answers: Uncheck "Find in selection" if it is checked (which it probably is when you are struggling with it and in despair googled the problem, and then found this SO entry). Only then select the lines and then re-check "Find in selection".

Comment: Unchecking "Find in Selection" sucks very much. It removes all of the new selection. It is quite unintuitive to select only after deselecting because any other editor I know can do it without deselecting first.

Alternatively, you can press ESC which closes the search window without deleting the new selection. I set it so that opening the search prompt with a selection across multiple lines will enable "Find in Selection" automatically. I just don't understand, why VSCode isn't able to do it for a selection within a single line.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu, highlight the lines where you want to make changes, press alt-L and then ctrl-H.  Then type the name you want to replace and replacement name in the top right dropdown.

Or some combination of these actions depending on whether the dropdown is already open or you're already in alt-L mode.  I'm still learning but thought I'd share what's working.

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend to use vim/gvim for such kind of things. VSCode doesn't have a convenient interface for an advanced editing actions(especially when you repeat the same steps) compare with gvim

Comment: This is a fair critique.  Unbelievable that vscode can't reasonably handle this essential task