# limit 'find' search to selected text only in vs code editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the vs code editor edit/find menu, is there a way to find 'mySearch' in selected text ONLY? E.g., in a single large file, I want to select a block of text (say 60 lines) and edit/find 'mySearch' in the block I've selected, and not the rest of the file?
My goal is to ultimately to 'replace all' instances of 'mySearch' but ONLY in the block I've selected. 
Thanks.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/m6rxlk

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335619/find-and-replace-in-visual-studio-code/44339430#44339430