# Visual studio code, how to copy the file name

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the visual studio code, it has commands to `Copy Path` and `Copy Relative Path` (Ctrl+Shift+p->File: Copy Path of Active File). Is there a way I could copy the active file name instead of the whole path?

If there is no way copy the active file name. Is there a way I could write a script or something which creating a new command based on existing `Copy Path` and showing the new command in the `Command Palette`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The extension [Copy file name](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nemesv.copy-file-name) works like a charm!
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> gives you *filename* and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> gives the *filename.extension*.

Comment: This gives an error when I tried to copy the file name of a .wav file, (cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document'))

Comment: Use command + shift + X to access the extensions pane (or click on it from the vertical bar on the leftmost part of the screen).

Comment: On macOS, I think it's [command + option + f](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73093267/5783745), which unfortunately overrides  the shortcut for find within selection (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73093267/5783745)).

Answer (score 6):

open your file on vscode> select file as active file> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> > <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
now you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste this path any where you want.

Comment: simple really....

Comment: What is that supposed to do? Open the command palette and then what? Nothing happens for me

Comment: That is not what was asked... The question was explicitly about NOT the file-path but just the file.name.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, if you see the active file in the "Explorer" view, you can type <kbd>F2</kbd> once you select it.

With VSCode 1.71 (Aug. 2022), you can type <kbd>F2</kbd> and:

- 1st press => prefix
- 2nd press => all
- 3rd press => suffix
- 4th press => cycles back around to prefix

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4544166/184671196-01adb871-a666-4065-9ad4-57b752f1fecc.gif]

This has been release to VSCode insider today, for you to test/play with it.

Answer (score 3):

- step1. first install "**copy file name**" extension from extensions(ctrl+shift+X) in your vscode.
- step2. then use **ctrl+alt+e** for copying the full file_name with file_extension(like .cpp or .py or .java etc..).
  or   **ctrl+alt+f** for for copying the file_name
  without file_extension.

Answer (score 2):

It is been a while but I found if you want to write a script using the currently opened file, create a new task in task.json and calling some scripts in the task might be a good option.

Basically, `${file}`, `${fileBasename}` and `${fileDirname}` are the variables that can be used in your script file.

Useful reference:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

Answer (score 1):

Without using any extensions, here's a combination of key shortcuts you can use to copy the path of the current file. It's a bit cumbersome but with some practice can be faster than doing the same using the mouse.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to open and focus the Explorer pane.
   The current file will be selected automatically by default.
2. <kbd>F2</kbd> to start renaming the file.
   This will select the file name without file extension.
3. (optional) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to include the file extension in the selection.
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy.
5. <kbd>Escape</kbd> to abort renaming (or just click anywhere).

Comment: It's just too complex

Answer (score 0):

The extension [File Utils](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sleistner.vscode-fileutils) also provides that capability along with others (`duplicate`, `move`, `rename`, `delete` for files and folders) through the context menu in the Explorer pane or a file tab, but not the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score -2):

If you arrived here wondering how to copy the full file name ***path***, it's:

1. Press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> then,
2. Press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

That will copy the file ***path*** to the clipboard.

Another way to copy the full (or relative) path is by right clicking on the relevant file tab (top of screen):

[image]

Comment: Question was for the file name, not the path

Answer (score -5):

no need any extensions, Ctrl+K -->  Ctrl+Shift+C, then you will get relative path

Comment: This opens me a terminal

Comment: my env is windows,  pressing  Ctrl+Shift+C directly will open a terminal. 
you should press Ctrl+K firstly , then press  Ctrl+Shift+C,  then could get a full path, you could paste it anywhere.
as for  relative path,  I configure it as shortcut Shift + Alt + C,  actually  you could configure/check  shortcuts from setting > Keyboard Shortcuts, and grep  "path", to see all related shortcut.

Comment: Question was for the file name, not the path nor the relative path