# javascript isn't running

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

i wrote this html document and the script isn't running

```js
alert("my name")
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  fvbnhjm
  <script type="text\javascript" src="JavaScript.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

i installed code runner in vs code and the only thing that i added to settings.json is this

```
"code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
"code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
"code-runner.executorMapByFileExtension": {

    ".js": "cd $dir $$ start $fileName",
    ".html": "cd $dir && start $fileName"
},
```

javascript isn't disabled in my browser, i don't need node.js here but i installed it

Comment: Remove the type="text\javascript" from the script tag, ensure that the JavaScript.js is on the same folder and try again.

Comment: `text\javascript` isn't the correct type for javascript. You can omit the type attribute, but if you're going to include it you need a `/` instead of `\\`.

Comment: @rayhatfield thank you very much, add this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

`text\javascript` isn't the correct type for javascript.

You can omit the type attribute, but if you're going to include it you need a `/` instead of `\`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see your folder structure, make sure you have type a valid path to your js file.

Looking for simple way to type the path? Just right click on your js file and click copy path. Then, paste it in src="file.js".

```html
<html>

<body>
  fvbnhjm
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can read more about it in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57600269/visual-studio-code-how-to-copy-the-file-name).

Thank you